# Install browserify error bundle.js not found

Tags: node.js, express

I already install browerify according to [this website](http://browserify.org/) but after all I got 404 error bundle.js not found. Help. I use the latest expressJS

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have the wrong path for bundle.js

ExpressJS can serve static file using this statement: `app.use(express.static('public'))` i.e., in the **public folder** of your site root

So. when you browserify be sure to output js in the public folder,like this:

`browserify path/to/js/main.js -o public/bundle.js`

then you can access your **bundle.js** through `domain.com/bundle.js`